# Regex match and replace operators in math operation

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

Given an input string

```
12/3
12*3/12
(12*54)/(3/4)
```

I need to find and replace each operator with a string that contains the operator

```
some12text/some3text
some12text*some2text/some12text
(some12text*some54text)/(some3text/some4text)
```

practical application:
From a backend (c#), i have the following string

```
34*157
```

which i need to translate to:

```
document.getElementById("34").value*document.getElementById("157").value
```

and returned to the screen which can be run in an eval() function.

So far I have

```
var pattern = @"\d+";
var input = "12/3;

Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
var matches = r.Matches(input);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
 // im at a loss what to match and replace here
}
```

Caution: i cannot do a blanket input.Replace() in the foreach loop, as it may incorrectly replace (12/123) - it should only match the first 12 to replace

Caution2: I can use string.Remove and string.Insert, but that mutates the string after the first match, so it throws off the calculation of the next match

Any pointers appreciated

Comment: Really, is [`Regex.Replace(s, @"\d+", "document.getElementById(\"$&\").value")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b&i=12%2f3%0d%0a12*3%2f12%0d%0a%2812*54%29%2f%283%2f4%29&r=document.getElementById%28%22%24%26%22%29.value) that you need? Why use `Regex.Matches`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
string pattern = @"\d+"; //machtes 1-n consecutive digits
var input = "(12*54)/(3/4)";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "some$0Text");
```

`$0` is the character group matching the pattern `\d+`. You can also write

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => "some"+ m.Groups[0]+ "Text");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JUknx2

Comment: Amazing - love the simplicity!